# unsigned int to significant number

Tags: c++, int, hex, decimal, unsigned

Hello I am working on a project. Get unsigned 16 bit numbers and average them. No problem with getting average but when I tried to print to the screen, it prints meaningless symbols. So I figured out that I must convert it to decimal. Vs2015 converts it but I want to do it myself because my code is for a microprocessor.
Here is my simulation...

```
int main(){

uint32_t  x = 0x12345678;
unsigned char c[4];

c[0] = x >> 24;// least significant 
c[1] = x >> 16;
c[2] = x >> 8;
c[3] = x;   // most significant
cout << x << endl;
cout << c[0] << endl;
cout << c[1] << endl;
cout << c[2] << endl;
cout << c[3] << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Output:

```
305419896 


4
V
x
```

Comment: `x >> 24` is the msb, not the lsb.

Comment: Try `cout << (int)c[0] << endl;` instead of `cout << c[0] << endl;`. Or, `cout << +c[0] << endl;`.

Comment: In the ASCII character set,  a character with value `0x12` is a line feed, a character with value `0x34` is the character `'4'`, a character with value `0x56` is the character `'V'`, and the character with value `0x78` is a `'x'`.   Compare that observation with the output you are getting.

Comment: sidenote: this code is platform-depended, check big endian and little endian

Comment: @Peter yes it matched .

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, that the inserter operator `<<` will treat `char` variables as character and not as a number. So, if the `char` variable contains 65, it will not print 65 but 'A'.

You need to convert the value to an `unsigned int`.

So:

```
std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(c[0]) << "\n";
```

Then it will give you the expected output.

Comment: You should cast to an `unsigned int` instead

Comment: To print the hex value you will rather do it this way: `std::cout << hex << static_cast<int>(c[0]) << "\n";`